# Nested for Loops in Python- creating a two dimensional array/list of lists

Tags: python, for-loop, nested-loops

New to Python here.  I just need a little bit of clarification on how the first "list of lists" is all 0's in the output below...is the first iteration of a loop the zeroth iteration?

```
#collect input from the user as integers

X=int(input("Enter a Value for 'X': "))
Y=int(input("Enter a Value for 'Y': "))
print("")
#define the outermost list as an empty list
outerlist=[]
#outermost loop should control the outermost list
#create that one first...outerlist
for i in range (X):
    #now create the innerlist
    innerlist=[]
    #append the innerlist 'Y' number of times
    for j in range(Y):

        innerlist.append(i*j)
    outerlist.append(innerlist)

print(outerlist)
```

Output:

Question 1:

```
Enter a Value for 'X': 3
Enter a Value for 'Y': 5

[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [0, 2, 4, 6, 8]]
```

Comment: The range for `i` is 0-2. The first element is `0` so the the entire first list is zeros.

Comment: Please repeat your tutorials on loops and `range`.  Yes, the first value is 0.

Answer (score 0):

Because the `range(N)` function by default iterates from zero to `N-1`. To iterate from 1 to N, you should have starting and ending value. for example `range(1, N+1)` will iterate from 1 to N.

I have corrected your code as follows:

```
# collect input from the user as integers

X = int(input("Enter a Value for 'X': "))
Y = int(input("Enter a Value for 'Y': "))
print("")
# define the outermost list as an empty list
outerlist = []
# outermost loop should control the outermost list
# create that one first...outerlist
for i in range(1, X + 1):
    # now create the innerlist
    innerlist = []
    # append the innerlist 'Y' number of times
    for j in range(1, Y + 1):
        innerlist.append(i * j)
    outerlist.append(innerlist)

print(outerlist)
```

Answer (score 0):

How the nested loops works is that, you start with the first element of the outer loop, inside it, you run the whole inside loop, finish it, move to the second element of the outer loop, finish all the elements of the inside loop etc...

**The final loop has the size of the outer loop, and the numbers of elements in it of the inner loop**
Let me give you an example with your 2 lists.

```
Size of X is 3
Size of Y is 5
Goes into X[0] -> Fill that element with the 5 inputs 0 * y[0], then 0 * y[1]... etc
Goes to X[1] -> Fills it with the 5 inputs of 1  * Y[0], then 1 * Y[1] ..
goes into X[2] -> same thing as before
```

Final list would be
[ **[** 0*y[0], 0*y[1], 0*y[2],0*y[3], 0*y[4]**]**, **[** 1*y[0], 0*y[1], 0*y[2], 0*y[3], 0*y[4], 0*y[5] **]** ...etc